# why do I not find generated source files for grpc and protobuf when using maven and java in vscode

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, grpc-java

I have a pom file that correctly generates the grpc and protobuf source files I need in target/generated-sources when run from the command line. But when I build in vscode those directories are empty and references to the protobufs are undefined. Here's the section of my pom file that builds the grpc source.

```
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.5.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.2.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
                    <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                    <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpc.version}:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I added the following based on what I read in other posts to prevent vscode/eclipse from removing the generated source directories

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  </plugin>
           <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>add-source</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>add-source</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <sources>
            <source>target/generated-sources/protobuf/grpc-java</source>
            <source>/target/generated-sources/protobuf/java</source>
          </sources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

When vs-code builds, the target generated-source directories are there, but there is no source in them. We had a similar problem with intellij but were able to work around it by running the maven command line build before opening intellij but that does not seem to work for vscode.

Comment: Hey, have you been able to resolve this? Recently moved to vs code and this stuff is annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `protoc-jar-maven-plugin` instead.

Sample usage please view [protoc-jar-maven-plugin](https://os72.github.io/protoc-jar-maven-plugin/index.html).

Comment: Using that plugin the protobuf classes get generated, but they don't seem to be visible in any other modules. Code builds fine using maven from the command line, but when I edit a module that depends on the protobuf module all the protobuf imports can not be resolved.

Comment: @JeffGaer. Please open a new issue to describe your question and if convenient, you may share the project.